# How to use Word2Vec's vocab of one model into another?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gensim

I have a `Doc2Vec's` model and I want to create `Word2vec's` model with different dimension. How can I use Doc2Vec's model `vocab` for fast training? Or is it `feasible` to train like this? Does `vocab building` has any effect on `train`?

Answer (score 1):

`vocab building` is essentially just one pass over the entire dataset and doesn't impact the training time much (unless you are training over billions of words).

Gensim's Doc2Vec (to the best of my knowledge) doesn't currently allow creating models from pre-defined vocabulary. If you are using Mikolov's code for sentence2vec (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/word2vec-toolkit/Q49FIrNOQRo/J6KG8mUj45sJ), it will allow you to save vocab and read from vocab.

```
word2vec -save-vocab <file>
word2vec -read-vocab <file>
```

Comment: What if I do something like (Word2Vec model).vocab = (Doc2vec model).vocab and then train on the same sentences?

Comment: I don't think it would work. Doc2Vec can take pre-trained vectors for initialisation, but otherwise it just reads the dataset `n+1` times (n = num of passes you set in the options).

You can easily test it though - Just initialise the vocab in this way, rebuild the model and print vocab.